# How to make QCombobox hide popup and keep focus when a window has Escape button as shortcut key

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, pyside2, qcombobox

I have a form created using Pyside2.

I have a QCombobox in a form that also has a QToolbutton. The QToolbutton has a shortcut using the Escape key to close the window if triggered.

When my Combobox displays its popup and I press the Escape key the form is closed too.

What I want is when Combobox popup is shown and I press Escape it only hides the popup, not close the window as well.

How can I do that?

Here example of the code:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox, QToolButton, QShortcut

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        toolbutton = QToolButton()
        toolbutton.setText("Press Esc to close window")
        toolbutton.setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt.Key_Escape))
        toolbutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        combobox = QComboBox()
        combobox.addItems("A")
        combobox.addItems("B")
        combobox.addItems("C")

        layout.addWidget(toolbutton)
        layout.addWidget(combobox)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Linux. Besides, why aren't you using a QDialog instead, which already implements the escape keys on its own by default? (btw, please write a comment whenever you update your post, so that people could get a notification or, at least, clearly find out that you *did* make changes: we cannot follow *all* posts).

Comment: I am using the windows system. And my application contains several forms for browsing and editing data. So in every form, I place a toolbar that uses a shortcut key. One of them is for closing the form.

Comment: If you were using a QToolBar (and expecting to use it in the standard way, allowing the floating mode, rearranging, etc) then I'd understand the need of QMainWindow, but that doesn't seem your case: you're just adding a button, so you can use QDialog instead.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a shortcut for this as its activation priority is too high. The window must only receive the event if no other widget wants it. A `QDialog` will handle this automatically, but if that cannot be used, a simple solution is to override the `keyPressEvent` of the window.

Here's a demo based on your example:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import Qt
from PySide2.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QComboBox, QToolButton, QShortcut

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        # DO NOT SET A SHORTCUT ON THIS BUTTON
        toolbutton = QToolButton()
        toolbutton.setText("Press Esc to close window")
        toolbutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        combobox = QComboBox()
        combobox.addItem("A")
        combobox.addItem("B")
        combobox.addItem("C")

        layout.addWidget(toolbutton)
        layout.addWidget(combobox)

        w = QWidget()
        w.setLayout(layout)

        self.setCentralWidget(w)
        self.show()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        # handle escape/cancel key
        if event.matches(QKeySequence.Cancel):
            self.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
app.exec_()
```